# Django NoReverseMatch when redirecting to view

Tags: python, django, redirect, view, django-urls

After loging in correctly, I want to redirect the user to another page so I use redirect, but I get a NoReverseMatch error.

```
Reverse for 'watchfilms' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

I don't know what's going wrong so I'm showing you my urls.py and views.py files. Maybe you see something wrong...

project's url.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^films/', include('films.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

app's url.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'films.views.index'),
    url(r'^signup$', 'films.views.signUp'),
    url(r'^login$', 'films.views.logIn'),
    url(r'^signedupok$', 'films.views.signedUpOk'),
    url(r'^watchfilms$', 'films.views.watchFilms'),
    url(r'^logout$', 'films.views.logout'),
)
```

views.py

```
...

def logIn(request):
    error = ""
    username = request.POST.get('username', False)
    pass = request.POST.get('password', False)
    user = authenticate(username = username, password = pass)
    if username or pass:
            if user is not None:
                    if user.is_active:
                            login(request, user)
                            return redirect('watchfilms')
                    else:
                            error = 'Error while login!'
            else:
                    errorea = 'Data is not correct!'
    return render(request, 'films/login.html', {'error': error})

@login_required
def watchFilms(request):
    film_list = Film.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(film_list, 3)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
            films = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
            films = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
            films = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    return render(request, 'films/watchFilms.html', {'films': films})

...
```

Once login is OK, watchFilms view should be called but it looks like it cannot be found (I don't get it why, I think urls.py is OK)...

Comment: add a name to each url in your url patterns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should name your url pattern if you want to reverse it:

```
url(r'^watchfilms$', 'films.views.watchFilms', name='watchfilms'),
```

Make sure the capitalisation is the same as in your `redirect()` call (i.e. all lowercase).

Answer (score 0):

The [**`redirect`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) function takes as input a model, a view, or an absolute or relative url.

Django is however complaining that it can not find any URL for the given parameter.

Probably the best thing is to pass a reference to the view function, such that if you later change the url, it will still work:

```
def logIn(request):
    error = ""
    username = request.POST.get('username', False)
    passw = request.POST.get('password', False)
    user = authenticate(username = username, password=passw)
    if username or passw:
            if user is not None:
                    if user.is_active:
                            login(request, user)
                            return redirect(watchFilms)
                    else:
                            error = 'Error while login!'
            else:
                    errorea = 'Data is not correct!'
    return render(request, 'films/login.html', {'error': error})
```

Please do not use a variable named `pass`. `pass` is a Python keyword, and usually the interpreter will error on this.